# android: How to create overlay blend like photoshop?

Tags: android, overlay, bit-manipulation, porter-duff, graphic-effects

I am tring achive overlay blend (like photoshop)in my android application. I have tried differnt PorterDuff.Modes (i.e. SCREEN, MYLTIPLY etc) with differnt combinations but could not achive the perfect overlay effect. 
Is there a way to achive effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PorterDuff overlay Mode as i shown below. It will work on the API level 11 or higher.

```
 Compose.setXfermode(new android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.OVERLAY));
```